# Remove float numbers outside the range and keep numbers inside the range in textfile

Tags: c#

First of all, i have a set of random float numbers in a text file, i have successfully make a code that is able to read the numbers from the text file after compilation. Now i need to create a number range and remove the numbers that are outside the range from the text file and only keep the numbers within the range inside text file. Lets say for example, i wanna keep only numbers that are within 743 and 1000 and remove the rest from the text file.

Please assist me in the matter. Thank you.

I have tried making codes which shown below, however it does not show the expected result. After compilation, my text file is empty, meaning all the numbers in the text file are removed.

This is the set of random float numbers i created in text file:

```
743.6 
742.8
744.7
743.2
1000
1768.6
1750
1767
1780
1500
```

And my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)


    {

        string usersPath = "C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile.txt";

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersPath).ToList();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(usersPath);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            double x = double.Parse(line);

            if (x > 740.7 && x < 1500.6)
            {
                writer.Write(line);
              //Console.WriteLine(line);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        writer.Close();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Aside from needing to replace `Write` with `WriteLine`, and having to press the return/enter key on every single line (owing to the position of your `Console.ReadLine()`, your code works as you expect, and the file isn't empty. Can you explain more about the problem you're facing? What happens when you debug?

Comment: You need to remove `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: To Mr Chetan, if i do that there is an error: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: @user See TheGeneral's answer, point 3. You're probably reading an empty line or something, and an empty line is not a `double`.

Comment: alright Mr John, i will look further into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a big nasty `Console.ReadLine().`Meaning, you are asking for user input and the program never writes a line.

However there are other issues

1. You are using `writer.Write(line);` instead of `writer.WriteLine(line);`, this will mash everything to the one line
2. You should be using a `using` statement
3. `double.Parse` will throw an exception if it hits a blank line or something unexpected, you could use `double.TryParse` instead
4. You could use `File.WriteAllLines` instead.
5. As an added bonus you could do this all in `LINQ`

Your Fixed Code

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersPath);

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(usersPath))
{
   foreach (var line in lines)
      if(double.TryParse(line,out var value) && value > 740.7 && value < 1500.6)
          writer.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Or a more succinct example with fault tolerance

```
string usersPath = $"C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile.txt";


// read all lines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersPath)

                 // for each line, try and and convert it double, if not return null
                .Select(x => double.TryParse(x, out var value) ? value : (double?)null)

                 // filter all nulls and values outside of the range
                .Where(x => x != null && x > 740.7 && x < 1500.6)

                 // convert each element to a string
                .Select(x => x.ToString());

// write all lines
File.WriteAllLines(usersPath, lines);
```

**Additional Resources**

[File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Double.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[File.WriteAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then
>   closes the file.

Comment: Shall i comment off the whole foreach loop then. and paste the above example below the streamwriter statement?

Comment: @user11612402 you can replace all but this line `usersPath`

Comment: so , below the line where i declare the user path statement?

Comment: Could you explain what u have done in particular what u have done? so that i can understand

Comment: If i wanna add more that 1 number range, should i use continue using the && at Where statement?

Comment: @user11612402 yes

Comment: .Where(x => x != null && x > 740.7 && x < 1000 && x > 1000 && x < 1680 )  when i add more than 1 range  like the one above, the text file becomes empty.

Comment: ((x > 740.7 && x < 1000) || (x > 1000 && x < 1680))       there is an error here, where all the x above is not in the current context.

Comment: Now the text file is empty.

Comment: @user11612402 .Where(x => x != null && ((x > 7 && x < 15) || (x > 16 && x < 17)))` yeah sorry with all the stuff going around we forgot the or `||`

Comment: Genius!  may i know why u used OR operator?

Comment: @user11612402 because you are asking, give me this range, or that range, or another range

Comment: shouldnt it be "and that range and another range" cause OR is like choosing either one range

Comment: @user11612402 no if you think about this, how can 2 numbers be in 2 or more ranges. They can be only in one range at once. if you have an *and*, it will never find anything unless they overlap

Comment: Anyways i can do the same thing for Y - coordinate ? cause thinking of including co ordinates in the text file, like number range within X & Y coordinates?

Comment: @user11612402 yup you can, give it a try, when you have a problem probably best to make a new question so other people can jump in as well, make sure you explain it well, show you input, show your code, and the problem you are having